# How to properly add a torsional_spring element to a RigidBodyTree in Drake

Tags: simulation, drake

I am using the Drake simulator, and attempting to add joint stiffness to the Acrobot demo found in the [underactuated robotics repo](https://github.com/RussTedrake/underactuated.git), and so far have been unable to successfully integrate such stiffness into the simulation.

I am running the script torque_slider_demo.py, which references the URDF file acrobot.urdf. I modified this URDF to include a torsional spring entry as follows:

```
<torsional_spring stiffness = "100000000" rest_angle = ".75">
   <joint name = "shoulder"/>
 </torsional_spring>
```

This element is added after defining joints (Full XML shown below), and I increased damping in both joints to more quickly see steady-state behavior.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<robot xmlns="http://drake.mit.edu"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 name="Acrobot">

  <link name="base_link">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.2 0.2 0.2" />
      </geometry>
      <material name="green">
        <color rgba="0 1 0 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
  </link>

  <link name="upper_link">
    <inertial>
      <origin xyz="0 0 -.5" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass value="1" />
      <inertia ixx="1" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.083" iyz="0" izz="1" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 -0.5" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="1.1" radius="0.05" />
      </geometry>
      <material name="red">
        <color rgba="1 0 0 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
  </link>

  <link name="lower_link">
    <inertial>
      <origin xyz="0 0 -1" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass value="1" />
      <inertia ixx="1" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.33" iyz="0" izz="1" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 -1" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
         <cylinder length="2.1" radius=".05" />
      </geometry>
      <material name="blue">
        <color rgba="0 0 1 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
  </link>

  <joint name="shoulder" type="continuous">
    <parent link="base_link" />
    <child link="upper_link" />
    <origin xyz="0 0.15 0" />
    <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
    <dynamics damping="1" />
  </joint>

  <joint name="elbow" type="continuous">
    <parent link="upper_link" />
    <child link="lower_link" />
    <origin xyz="0 0.1 -1" />
    <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
    <dynamics damping="1" />
  </joint>

  <torsional_spring stiffness = "100000000" rest_angle = ".75">
    <joint name = "shoulder"/>
  </torsional_spring>

  <transmission type="SimpleTransmission" name="elbow_trans">
    <actuator name="elbow" />
    <joint name="elbow" />
    <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
  </transmission>


</robot>
```

With this absurdly high stiffness value, I would expect for the arm to stabilize around the resting angle of the spring and exhibit an obvious pull towards the resting angle, however I do not see these effects in the visualization produced by the script.

Am I improperly defining the torsional spring in the URDF? Do I need to do some other setup to tell the simulator to consider joint stiffness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like we have support for torsional springs, but don't actually load them from URDF (nor expose the interface in python):
https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/attic/multibody/test/rigid_body_tree/rigid_body_tree_spring_test.cc

It would not be hard to add, and we'd welcome the contribution if you want to add the few lines to the parser.  The drake developers are focused on multibodyplant now (which will replace rigidbodyplant).